# Encapsulating mutable slice modification

Tags: rust

Given a function `foo` which takes a mutable reference to a slice. It can decrease the length of the slice with `a = &mut a[1..]`. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to write a function that mutates `a` in the same way.

```
fn foo(mut a: &mut [i32]) {

    a = &mut a[1..];

    inc(&mut a);
}

fn inc<'a: 'b, 'b>(s: &'b mut &'a mut [i32]) {
   *s = &mut s[1..];
}
```

`inc` is an attempt at writing such a function. However, it fails with:

```
Output of rustc nightly (Compiler #1)
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
 --> <source>:3:9
  |
2 | fn inc<'a: 'b, 'b>(s: &'b mut &'a mut [i32]) {
  |                       ---------------------
  |                       |
  |                       these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
3 |    *s = &mut s[1..];
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `s` flows into `s` here
```

Comment: You could have the function take a mutable slice and return a mutable slice instead of taking a mutable slice by mutable reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler example of the error is

```
fn oops<'a: 'b, 'b>(a: &'b mut &'a mut i32) {
    let _: &'a mut i32 = *a; // error!
}
```

The issue here is that having `a` (a mutable reference to some data) lets you *mutate* (change) the value it points to, but it does not let you *move* the value (leaving nothing behind). In `oops`, since you can only have one mutable reference to anything at a time, `*a` needs to be moved to `_`, but that leaves `*a` without data and `a` pointing to "garbage". But whoever lent `*a` to `oops` expects `*a` to have a value upon it returning, so this must be banned. (I say "garbage" because the move probably doesn't really mutate `*a`, and if we forced this to execute probably nothing would go wrong. But if we didn't care about performance, the move could in principle destroy `*a` to enforce the "one mutable borrow" rule, in which case you're hosed.)

In your case, `index_mut` (which is implementing the `[1..]` syntax) takes `&mut [i32]`, so `*s` needs to be moved to the function. But that leaves `*s` without a value, and you don't own `*s`, which is illegal. It doesn't matter that you will eventually put a value back. E.g. if `index_mut` panics, the caller will be expecting a value in whatever variable it lent to `inc`, but there won't be any. In contrast, `foo` *does* own `a`, so it's okay to leave `a` valueless for the duration of `index_mut` in `a = &mut a[1..]` (the compiler can track when owned variables have and don't have values).

One fix (without changing the interface) is to stick a default value into `*s` while you're operating on it. The `impl<'a, T> Default for &'a mut[T]` provides this (the default value points to an empty slice), and `std::mem::take` packages that `Default` implementation in a safe way.

```
fn inc<'a: 'b, 'b>(s: &'b mut &'a mut [i32]) {
   *s = &mut std::mem::take(s)[1..];
}
```

I agree with @cdhowie that writing

```
fn inc<'a>(s: &'a mut [i32]) -> &'a mut [i32] {
  return s[1..];
}
```

and requiring usage by `a = inc(a)` is a better idea than the `inc(&mut a)` interface.

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation. Thanks for sharing it!