# Indirectly moving slice indicies in Rust

Tags: rust

In C, I can write the following code:

```
void inc(int** pointer){
    *pointer = *pointer + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int myarray[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int* mypointer = myarray;
    
    inc(&mypointer);
    
    printf("%d", mypointer[0]); //prints 2

    return 0;
}
```

Where the main function has a pointer into an array (stack allocated in this case, but it doesn't need to be), and it can hand off a pointer to that pointer to another function, which could then do things with that array, but could also change the part of  the array that the pointer in the original function points to.  To the best of my understanding, a borrowed slice in rust is analogous to a pointer into an array.  Is it possible to write code that does this sort of thing in rust in a safe and idiomatic way, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rust type you'd be looking for here is `&mut &mut [i32]`, but reassigning the outer mutable reference to part of the inner mutable slice [creates a confusing lifetime problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71551690/501250).

Instead, you could have the `inc` function return a new slice, which would be similar to the C prototype `int * inc(int *)`.  For example:

```
fn inc(v: &mut [i32]) -> &mut [i32] {
    &mut v[1..]
}

fn main() {
    let mut myarray = [1, 2, 3];
    let mut mypointer = &mut myarray[..];
    
    mypointer = inc(mypointer);

    println!("{}", mypointer[0]);
}
```

You can make it work with `&mut &mut [i32]` but it requires a rather esoteric use of `std::mem::take()`:

```
use std::mem::take;

fn inc(v: &'_ mut &'_ mut [i32]) {
    *v = &mut take(v)[1..]
}

fn main() {
    let mut myarray = [1, 2, 3];
    let mut mypointer = &mut myarray[..];
    
    inc(&mut mypointer);

    println!("{}", mypointer[0]);
}
```

Comment: So essentially "no, there isn't a safe way to do this in rust"?
If I'm doing this, is there any benefit to actually having the borrows be `&mut` and not just `&`?

Comment: @TheZachMan There is a safe way to accomplish the task, but not with the exact same mechanism you use in C. And yes, generally you should not use mutable references when you could easily use shared references.

Comment: Ah, I think the question you linked was exactly what I wanted to know